# Sign-in options problem in chromium with podman on wsl

Tags: chrome, windows-subsystem-for-linux, key-authentication, podman

I have some usage on aws-cli command on wsl debian/ubuntu no matter what distro, in which before some transition to other account everything worked fine with AWS SAML endpoint. Authentication did not have gui option and worked directly with config option. Now migration on new tenant company have configuration to use --mode gui. Problem with that I should get with chromium option which is using hello Pin but with pop up I get only sing in with password (can do passwordless) and sign in with a security key.

There is two possible problems either on company configuration they screw something or on chromium when aws saml it gets me not correct options on sign in. Also on first pop up getting:
*Your profile can not be used because it is from a newer version of Chromium.
Some features may be unavailable. Please specify a different profile directory or use a newer version of Chromium.*

Is there some configuration inside chromium which I can enable PIN authentication?